# How to add custom link after order and returns in footer of magento

Tags: magento, hyperlink, customization, footer

Could someone tells me how to positionate custom link after order and returns link and before contacts us? 
I already added links by using code snippet in local.xml:

```
<reference name="footer_links">
  <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
   <label>Link1</label>
   <url>Link1</url>
   <title>Link1</title>
   <prepare>true</prepare>
  </action> 
</reference>
```

but I cannot put that links between orders and contacts us links. 
`<position>1</position>` not working

Please advice!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve that problem by myself. 
in app\design\frontend\customtheme\default\layout\contacts.xml add after `<reference name="footer_links">` the code below:

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label title"><label>mylinklabel</label><url>mylink-url</url><title>mylinktitle</title><prepare>true</prepare></action>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way i did it was to create a footer.phtml in PACKAGE/TEMPLATE/app/template/page/html/footer.phtml putting in a call to the CMS Footer Page I built with the links i want.

```
<div class="footer-container">
<div class="footer">
    <div class="quicknavHolder"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?></div>
   <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('sm-footer')->toHtml(); ?> 
        <address><?php echo $this->getCopyright() ?></address>
</div>
```

Then in the CMS Block called "sm-footer" i put all the links i want in the order i want them in.

```
<center>
<table style="padding-bottom: 15px; text-transform: uppercase;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><!--Privacy Policy-->{{widget type="cms/widget_page_link" template="cms/widget/link/link_block.phtml" page_id="63"}}</td>
<td style="padding: 0 12px;">|</td> 
<td><!--FAQ-->{{widget type="cms/widget_page_link" template="cms/widget/link/link_block.phtml" page_id="44"}}</td>
<td style="padding: 0 12px;">|</td>
<td><!--My Account--><a href="{{store url="customer/account"}}">My Account</a></td>
<td style="padding: 0 12px;">|</td>
<td><!--Contact Us-->{{widget type="cms/widget_page_link" template="cms/widget/link/link_block.phtml" page_id="45"}}</td>
<td style="padding: 0 12px;">|</td>
<td><!--Category Sitemap--><a href="{{store url='catalog/seo_sitemap/category/'}}">Category Sitemap</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</center>
```

This is just an option.